# On Android, how to catch all touch up/touch down events happening in the area of a View?

Tags: java, android, multi-touch, touch-event

I define a custom view like this:

```
public class MyView extends View{

    String name;

    MyView(Context context, String name){
        super(context);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = ev.getActionMasked();
        if(action ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            Log.v("MyView", name + " down");                       
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            Log.v("MyView", name + " up");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now if I create two MyView instances like this.

```
MyView view1 = new MyView("view1");
MyView view2 = new MyView("view2");
```

and if I add them to a layout inside my Activity: here's what happens:

when touching only the area of view1 I get "view1 up" and "view1 down" messages in the logs.
When touching only the area of view2 I get "view2 up" and "view2 down" messages in the logs.
However, when I touch the view1, don't release my finger and touch view2, I don't get any message.

If, in my code I add the `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN`, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int action = ev.getActionMasked();
    if(action ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
        Log.v("MyView", name + " down");                      
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP){
        Log.v("MyView", name + " up");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, if I touch view1, don't release my finger and touch view2, I get log messages, but still from view1!
I'd like that events happening on the area of view2 be routed to view2. How to do that?